# Upload photo to a specific drive folder

Tags: android, photo, drive

I'm using drive REST API and I would like to know how could I upload some photo to Google Drive?

The Docs give me this :

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

JPEG data
```

But I have no idea how I can find `my_auth_token`.

I'm already able to create a file in the drive in a specific folder, but how can I upload the "content" of my photo to the empty file created in drive?

Is there another method to select photo from gallery / take photos with camera and then upload these photos directly to Google Drive other than the drive REST API?